# How do I cast to a constant in ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a C function that takes a const double pointer in the third input pos:

```
PI_MOV(int ID, const char* szAxes, const double* pdValueArray)
```

When I try to use a double pointer:

```
pos = C.POINTER(C.c_double)
pos.value = 2.0

GCS_api.PI_MOV(controller_number, szAxis1, pos)
```

I get an argument type error for position 3:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3
```

How do I convert pos, the 3rd argument, into the constant double pointer that is desired?  This function works as a plain old double in C++ Visual Studio actually, so not quite clear why is needs to be a const double*.  Any suggestions?

I tried to specify the argument types for the function:

```
GCS_api.PI_MOV.argtypes = [C.c_int, C.POINTER(C.c_char), C.POINTER(C.c_double)]
```

But this also gave an error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType
```

If I stick with the original and pass a ctypes double * constant I think I could be ok....

Comment: Note: I import ctypes as C

Comment: unrelated: If the second argument is meant to pass a C string (zero-terminated) then use`C.c_char_p` type instead of `C.POINTER(C.c_char)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, actually ctypes sets the `from_param` to the one from `c_char_p`. So in `argtypes`, `POINTER(c_char)` works the same as `c_char_p` -- except for `argtypes` of a callback (i.e. from C back into Python). Only simple types such as `c_char_p` have a `getfunc` defined that converts the passed in argument  value to a Python native type.

Comment: @eryksun: I believe you but let's not confuse future readers. `c_char_p` is not the same as `POINTER(c_char)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, of course it's not the same. I hope people can figure out for themselves that it's an entirely different base class, which also has a different metaclass. The two behave differently in other situations. Actually the `from_param` from `c_char_p` is hacked into `POINTER(c_char)` when the pointer type cache is initially reset.

Comment: @user391339, even if `pos` were a pointer instance instead of a type, setting `value` would be ignored (harmlessly set in the instance dict). A `_Pointer` subclass has a `contents` descriptor. Only simple types (plus `c_char` and `c_wchar` arrays) have a `value` descriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pos = C.POINTER(C.c_double)` creates a type.  You want an instance of a `c_double` and pass the address to the function:

```
d = C.c_double(2.0)
GCS_api.PI_MOV(controller_number, szAxis1, C.byref(d))
```

Since the function may want an array of doubles, this is the syntax for that:

```
d = (C.c_double*4)(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)  # Create double[4] array
```

Comment: it the function accepts an array then why is there no `size` parameter?

Comment: Ask the author.  The name of the parameter is `pdValueArray`.  If it only takes a single double, why a pointer as well?

Comment: Its an API for controlling motorized stages.  If there is one stage attached to the controller then a double for the set position suffices, but if more than one stage is connected you can pass two positions.   Still not sure how I am able to pass a straight double and not a double array in C, but I dont know that language too well.  In C variable was passed in as &pos, and originally declared as double pos.

Comment: @user391339, C passes an array parameter as a pointer to its first element. The length is lost unless passed explicitly, e.g. `PI_MOV(int ID, const char *szAxes, size_t cntValueArray, const double *pdValueArray)`.